# Tornado logging configuration - why am I getting duplicate lines?

Tags: python, logging, tornado

I use the following logging configuration:

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": false,
    "formatters": {
        "simple": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s %(name)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(processName)-10s %(message)s"
        }
    },

    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "simple",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
        }
    },

    "loggers": {
        "transmit": {
            "level":"DEBUG",
            "propagate": "no",
            "handlers": ["console"]
        },
    },

    "root": {
        "level": "INFO",
        "handlers": ["console"]
    }
}
```

In my main, i use the following to set up the logging :

```
with open('logging.conf', 'rt') as f:
    config = json.load(f) 
logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```

Each module requests a logger in the following way:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("transmit.%s" % __name__)
```

For some reason I see the logs from both my modules and tornado ones, printed twice:

```
2014-01-09 14:53:07,111 transmit.__main__ DEBUG    MainProcess Current working dir : /Users/dimap/workspace/PycharmProjects/Transmit
2014-01-09 14:53:07,111 transmit.__main__ DEBUG    MainProcess Current working dir : /Users/dimap/workspace/PycharmProjects/Transmit
2014-01-09 14:53:12,619 transmit.__main__ INFO     MainProcess Get com
2014-01-09 14:53:12,619 transmit.__main__ INFO     MainProcess Get com
2014-01-09 14:53:12,620 tornado.access  INFO     MainProcess 200 GET /com?op=verify (127.0.0.1) 1.65ms
2014-01-09 14:53:12,620 tornado.access  INFO     MainProcess 200 GET /com?op=verify (127.0.0.1) 1.65ms
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong ?
Thanks.

Comment: Found the answer :) I had an error in the configuration of loggers - it should be "propagate": false, and not "propagate": "no",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer :) I had an error in the configuration :
It should be 
`"propagate": false,` and not `"propagate": "no",`